# Bios Password problems

Tags: bios, firmware

I’ve got a little problem, Last year I switched from Windows to Linux. It has been a really good experience so far. However, last year I installed VMWare for having a Windows virtual machine, it happened that after that my BIOS password changed, I know it’s not normal and a bit illogical but it happened and now I need to restore it, since restoring it using Windows is kind of boring to me (I’m really into Linux) after a lot of research I found that this might work

```bsh
modprobe nvram
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvram
```

However I’m not sure what this does and I don’t want to make a mistake or do something that can harm my system.**My PC is a Lenovo ideapad 330s with Intel Core i5. My OS is Ubuntu Mate 20.04.** I would be really happy if you help me. ☺️

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Keltari's answer is correct, though I would add one item - when removing the battery when the jumper to clear CMOS is not available which most laptops don't have a jumper (you mentioned you have an Ideapad 330S):

1. unplug power to the system first.
2. open up the bottom of the laptop (you have to anyways to get to the CMOS battery)...
3. remove the cable for the big laptop battery from it's port (just the cable, you don't need to unscrew and remove the battery).  Take care to remove it by the plastic, NOT THE WIRES.
4. the CMOS battery is a round (button) battery wrapped in either yellow or black electrical tape usually and has a wire that runs to and plugs into the motherboard.  Remove that wire from the motherboard port.  Take care to remove it by the plastic, NOT THE WIRES.
5. press the power button with the power unplugged and the batteries disconnected
   ...shouldn't need to wait for an hour, just 30-60 seconds is all you'd need to clear the BIOS password.
6. Plug the CMOS battery wire back into the motherboard, same spot you removed it from
7. plug the big battery back into the motherboard, same spot you removed it from.
8. turn the laptop on.

I'd be worried about what set a BIOS password from your virtual machine or Vmware when you had no password previously.

Here's a video that might help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCPF1GMp4HU

Answer (score 0):

If you need to clear your BIOS password, look at the documentation for your motherboard.  Usually, there is a jumper you can set to clear the BIOS password.  Worst case, you can remove the CMOS battery for an hour or so.